# Dynamic select-option using objects in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have this object:

```
0: {year: "2015", period: ["P1"]}
1: {year: "2016", period: ["P1", "P2"]}
2: {year: "2017", period: ["P1", "P2", "P3"]}
```

And I wanna do 2 `select-option`:

> When I press on 2015 on the first `select-option`, the values on the second `select-option` to be
>   `P1`.
>
> When I press on 2016 on the first `select-option`, the values on the second `select-option` to be
>   `P1`, `P2`.
>
> When I press on 2017 on the first `select-option`, the values on the second `select-option` to be
>   `P1`, `P2`, `P3`.

Something dinamically basically. I tried this:

```
<select>
  <option disabled value="null">Select year</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of fps" [value]="item.year">
     {{ item.year }}
  </option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select>
  <option disabled value="null">Select period</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of fps" [value]="item.period">
     {{ item.period }}
  </option>
</select>
```

but this will give me: (same with 2016 and 2017)

[image]

How can I modify in order to obtain what I want? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Bind the first selection to a variable and use it to manipulate second

Comment: But how to use it? Can you give me some more details?

Comment: @PardeepJain thank you very much! And thank you all for your answers, I upvoted all of them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the selection of your first dropdown value to set another dropdown options, better to call event on every change of your dropdown's value. Use your code like below -

```
<select (change)='onSelect(val.value)' #val>
  <option disabled value="null">Select year</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item.year">
     {{ item.year }}
  </option>
</select>

<select>
  <option disabled value="null">Select period</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of periodOptions" [value]="item">
     {{ item }}
  </option>
</select>
```

and Bind in Your method like this -

```
options = [
    {year: "2015", period: ["P1"]},
    {year: "2016", period: ["P1", "P2"]},
    {year: "2017", period: ["P1", "P2", "P3"]}
  ];
  periodOptions = [];

  onSelect(val) {
    console.log(val);
    if (val) {
      this.periodOptions = [];
      this.options.map(res => {
        if(res.year == val){
          this.periodOptions = res.period;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

## <kbd>[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdwon-selection?file=src/app/app.component.ts)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In your TS, use a temporary variable to hold year selection

```
tempYearSelect : string = ''
```

HTML :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="tempYearSelect">
  <option disabled value="null">Select year</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of fps" [value]="item.year">
     {{ item.year }}
  </option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select>
  <option disabled value="null">Select period</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of fps" [value]="item.period" [hidden]="item.year!=tempYearSelect">
     {{ item.period }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
   <select [(ngModel)]="firstSelectValue">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of firstSelectOptions" [value]="opt">
       {{ opt }}
    </option>
   </select> 

   <select *ngIf="firstSelectValue" [(ngModel)]="secondSelectValue" >
    <option *ngFor="let opt of secondSelectOptions" [value]="opt">
      {{ opt }}
    </option>
  </select>


  <div>
    <div>First select value: {{ firstSelectValue }}</div>
    <div>Second select value:  {{ secondSelectValue }}</div>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

    private opts = [ 
      {year: "2015", period: ["P1"]},
      {year: "2016", period: ["P1", "P2"]},
      {year: "2017", period: ["P1", "P2", "P3"]}
  ]

  firstSelectValue = '2015';
  secondSelectValue = null;

  get firstSelectOptions() {
    return this.opts.map(({year}) => year);
  }

  get secondSelectOptions() {
    return (this.opts.find(({year}) => year === this.firstSelectValue)).period
  }

}
```

Link : [View Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycr695)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<select (change)="changeValue($event.target.value)">
<option disabled value="null">Select year</option>
<option *ngFor="let item of fps" [value]="item.year" (change)="changeValue(item.year)">
   {{ item.year }}
</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select>
<option disabled value="null">Select period</option>
<option *ngFor="let item of fps1" [value]="item">
   {{ item }}
</option>
</select>
```

TS code

```
 changeValue(year){
this.fps.forEach(element => {
  if(element.year==year){
    this.fps1=element.period;
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"My Angular way" when we have a few relationals options is using ngValue. The disapoint it's that in "year" we have an object, not a number, but the advantage is a clear .ts

```
<select [(ngModel)]="year" #val>
  <option disabled value="null">Select year</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of options" [ngValue]="item">
     {{ item.year }}
  </option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select [(ngModel)]="periodo">
  <option disabled value="null">Select period</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of year?.period" [value]="item">
     {{ item }}
  </option>
</select>
{{year?.year}}{{periodo}}
```

The .ts only need two variables year )that will be an object, but we can obtain the year by year.year) and periodo

See [stactblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdwon-selection-ns7wbe?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
export class AppComponent  {
  options = [
    {year: "2015", period: ["P1"]},
    {year: "2016", period: ["P1", "P2"]},
    {year: "2017", period: ["P1", "P2", "P3"]}
  ];
  year:any=null;
  period:any;
}
```